# Check T generic type has property S (generic) in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, properties, typeof

class A

```
class A{
...
}
```

class B

```
 class B:A{
    ...
 }
```

class C

```
 class C:A{
    B[] bArray{get;set;}
 }
```

I would like to check if T has a property type of S , create instance of S and assignment to that propery :

```
public Initial<T,S>() where T,S : A{
   if(T.has(typeof(S))){
      S s=new S();
      T.s=s;
   }
}
```

Comment: What if T has multiple Properties of Type S?

Comment: Alternatively, say "where T,S : C". if that is all the method does.

Comment: @Ralf thanks for the reminder, I didn't think about it :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best and easiest thing to do is implement this functionality using an interface.

```
public interface IHasSome
{
    SomeType BArray {get;set;}
}

class C:A, IHasSome
{
    public SomeType BArray {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can cast the object in your generic method:

```
public T Initial<T,S>() where T : new() where S : SomeType, new()
{
    T t = new T();

    if (t is IHasSome)
    {
        ((IHasSome)t).BArray = new S();
    }

    return t;
}
```

If that doesn't fit, you can use reflection to go over the properties and check their types. Set the variable accordingly.

Comment: I would expect the Initial method to return T rather then void. otherwise I can't see how it would be useful...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agreed. OP didn't specify the return type, so I just inserted `void`.

Comment: Yeah, I was just writing a comment to the question about that but them you posted your answer, so I decided to comment here instead. other then that, I agree - Interfaces are the way to go here.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @PatrickHofman that way is better, but if you want somethig more generic that creates a new instance for all properties of a type, you can do that using reflection:

```
public T InitializeProperties<T, TProperty>(T instance = null) 
    where T : class, new()
    where TProperty : new()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new T();

    var propertyType = typeof(TProperty);
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == propertyType);

    foreach(var propInfo in propertyInfos)
        propInfo.SetValue(instance, new TProperty());

    return instance;
}
```

Then:

```
// Creates a new instance of "C" where all its properties of the "B" type will be also instantiated
var cClass = InitializeProperties<C, B>();

// Creates also a new instance for all "cClass properties" of the "AnotherType" type
cClass = InitializeProperties<C, AnotherType>(cClass);
```